# production.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

On my local build everything works.  I recently deployed using Digital Ocean nginx.  When I try to upload an image I get the following error in my log file.

```
production.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

My php version is 7.1.18 and my Laravel Framework is 5.5.40.

I have read several posts about this error and not really sure how to fix this bug.  My php version seems correct, not sure where to upgrade it and if I need to upgrade it.

When I got to phpinfo I get the following

[image]
Any ideas of how to upgrade the server to 7.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of PHP used by `nginx`. This may be different than the one shown in your command line.

Do the following, create a simple PHP file and put it in your `public` folder:

**hello.php**

```
phpinfo()
```

Then hit `hello.php` in your browser.

UPDATE:

If the versions mismatch, check your `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. There must be something in there.. like the PHP version declared in the `fastcgi_pass`.

Comment: I am getting version 7.0 and when I look into my default file it points to /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock.  What do I do to change the version to 7.1?

Comment: Could you post the content of your `nginx` site configuration? (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`)

Comment: @Aaron glad to help.